# Is it possible to scale only UVs to a specific value?

Tags: uv

I need to scale the UVs of an object to exactly twice their current size. However, Blender does not seem to have a system put in place to get exact UV scaling. When you scale UVs, the scale operator is opened in the 3D view window, but editing this scales the object and returns the UVs to their original size.

Is there a script or operator I can use to achieve this?

Comment: Select your UV, and press S and then 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the image editor you can select your UVs and scale them just as you would do with vertices on the 3D viewport.

<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> will scale the selected UVs by two

<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>.5</kbd> wil scale the UVs to one half.

<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> will scale by two horizontally.

[image]